# Changing values for individual items inside an ng-repeat angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am very new to Angularjs...looking more for theory help here I guess then exact code. I am making a game, when you go into a new game map it loads the game map data and "enemies" which are objects that contain all the attributes for an enemy. Enemies have the same attributes but different values -

Enter a screen - this code essentially initializes the new map -

```
db.getThisMapHovers($scope.area).success(function(data){
  $scope.maphovers = data;
  $scope.room_url = data[0].room_url;
  var random_num = Math.random();
  random_num = random_num.toString();
  random_num = random_num.substring(3,2);
  var calculated_num = data[0].encounter_chance;
  if(random_num >= calculated_num){
     db.getNpcCombat(data[0].npc_combat_set).success(function(data){
       $scope.encounters = [];
      $scope.encounters = data;
       $scope.encounters.attack_count = 0; 
      $scope.the_encounter(data);
    });
  }
});
```

It loads the map and does a random number (simulating a dice roll) if that passes, it loads the enemies for an "encounter" into this HTML -

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div ng-repeat="encounter in encounters" class="col-md-4" ng-class="{'move_forward' : number == 100}">
        <img class="animated tada col-md-12" style="width:100px" src="{{encounter.combat_npc_img}}">
    <p>{{encounters.attack_count}}</p>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-model="attack" style="width: {{encounters.attack_count}}%">
    {{encounters.attack_count}}%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is loading fine...a different image for each "enemy" and each on has a progress bar set to 0.

and then runs this code (which is not doing what I want)...I am taking each progress bar from 0 and counting up to 100, once it reaches 100, stops the interval and run the $scope.attack function -

```
$scope.the_encounter = function(data){
   angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
      var set_timer = $interval(function() {
      $scope.encounters.attack_count += 1;
      if($scope.encounters.attack_count == 100){
         $interval.cancel(set_timer);
         $scope.attack(data);
    }
  }, value.attack_rate); 
  });
}
```

The attack function (eventually, I am going to make it randomly select a type of "attack" for each "enemy" make that code run and then start back over the progress counter back at 0.

I am creating a random number again, to cause a random delay in time, different for each "enemy" before the progress bar goes back to 0 and restarts the attack process.

```
$scope.attack = function(data){
    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
       var random_num = Math.random();
       random_num = random_num.toString();
       random_num = random_num.substring(2,7);
       $timeout(function(){
         $scope.encounters.attack_count = 0;  
         $scope.the_encounter(data);
  }, random_num);
});
}
```

The problem I am having is that the progress bars for all enemies are exactly the same. ...I thought with the foreach loop I have, it would affect each item differently, but it seems to be giving both the same values.

If someone could explain to me how I can add different timers to different items in the ng-repeat and also how I will be able to target singe items inside the loop, that would be great.

Comment: I am not sure as I haven't tried this code in a fiddle, but what I see is that the loop is using the same number for the interval. Why not create some randomness inside the loop itself? `$scope.encounters.attack_count += not_one_but_random;`

Comment: Note - When I print out the "enemy" objects, there is only 1 attack count outside of the enemy's objects...I was trying to create that in the programming. I added an "attack_count" row for each enemy in the database and now have that inside of each object. Going to try to manipulate it this way.

Comment: The thing is, the intervals are acting the same on every item...I want different speed intervals for different items.  -  }, value.attack_rate);

Comment: what are you storing here exactly ($scope.encounters = data;) , because later you are adding +1 to  $scope.encounters.attack_count...im a bit confused since before you are attaching an array

Comment: `value.attack_rate` seems to be coming from the server at this point: `db.getNpcCombat(data[0].npc_combat_set).success(function(data){ $scope.the_encounter(data);`. If you could make a jsfiddle would be much easier for anybody to answer and in the process maybe you could even find it yourself.

Comment: The encounters.attack_count is a $scope variable, it's the same for all elements. You must store the attack_count in every single encounter, and then reference in markup as: style="width: {{encounter.attack_count}}%" (not encounterS.attack_count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood correctly, but i made an example based on your source: http://jsfiddle.net/s94g9w24/3/.

Basically, you're using one global $scope variable ($scope.encounters.attack_count) and you reference that variable in your html (style="width: {{encounters.attack_count}}%"> {{encounters.attack_count}}%). I think you have to set the attack_count variable in each encounter object instead.

In the "the_encounter" function, set the attack_count variable of each encounter object:

```
$scope.the_encounter = function(data){
   angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
      var set_timer = $interval(function() {
      value.attack_count += 1; //set the attack_count in the 'value' object, not in the $scope
      if(value.attack_count == 100){
         $interval.cancel(set_timer);
    }
  }, value.attack_rate); 
});
```

In the html markup, you reference the encounter.attack_count variable:

```
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-model="attack" style="width: {{encounter.attack_count}}%">
    {{encounter.attack_count}}%
    </div>
```

Notice that the variable you were referencing was encounterS.attack_count, i changed to encounter.attack_count.

Comment: Perfect! Yep, spot on, I was changing attack_count in the wrong way. Thank you!

Comment: Only issue still though, not sure why, seems that in the attack function, they keep both restarting the process again at the same time...I am wanting to have a random period of time random period of time for the timeout for each item...do you see any reason it would keep resetting them at the same amount of time?

Comment: Post a JsFiddle, in my example the process doesn't restart. But it could be a similar reason (a global variable instead of a "local" one)